# SQL Condition based searching ,not working with AND condition

Tags: sql, search, sql-server-2017

I am implementing search operation (client side searching via stored procedure)
i have a 'Nvarchar' type column 'ArticleHeader' and a 'DATE' column 'DateEffective'
i am performing conditional based searching by passing @operator, 
for the fallowing snippet i am trying to search date and article header in Conjunction (AND)
i am getting no results how ever if i run them individually they works out fine.

Find the snippet :

```
CREATE TABLE #TempItems
(
    DateEffective DATE,
    ArticleHeader NVARCHAR(50)
)

insert into #TempItems values ('2019-12-28','Nieuws')
insert into #TempItems values ('2020-02-12','Test')
insert into #TempItems values ('2020-01-10','zolo')
insert into #TempItems values ('2020-02-23','valued')

declare @DateEffective datetime,@operator nvarchar(10)
--set @DateEffective ='2020-01-10'
set @operator='neq'
declare @ArticleHeader nvarchar (50) ='Nieuws'

select * from #TempItems PA
Where 1=1
--------------------------------------------------------------------
And
(
(
(@operator='neq') And
CASE WHEN @DateEffective IS NULL 
THEN '1900-1-1' 
ELSE convert(date,PA.DateEffective) 
END !=
CASE WHEN @DateEffective IS NULL 
THEN '1900-1-1' 
ELSE Convert(Date, @DateEffective)
End
)
OR
(
(@operator='eq') And
CASE WHEN @DateEffective IS NULL 
THEN '1900-1-1' 
ELSE convert(date,PA.DateEffective) 
END =
CASE WHEN @DateEffective IS NULL 
THEN '1900-1-1' 
ELSE Convert(Date, @DateEffective)
End
)
)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AND
(
(lower(@Operator) = 'eq' AND 
CASE WHEN @ArticleHeader IS NULL
            THEN '1'
            ELSE PA.ArticleHeader
      END =
      CASE WHEN @ArticleHeader IS NULL
                    THEN '1'
                    ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), @ArticleHeader)
      END
)
OR
(lower(@Operator) = 'startswith' AND 
CASE WHEN @ArticleHeader IS NULL
            THEN '1'
            ELSE PA.ArticleHeader
      END Like 
      CASE WHEN @ArticleHeader IS NULL
                    THEN '1'
                    ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), @ArticleHeader) + '%'
      END
)
)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: According to me it's working single conditions?

Comment: yes, if you only run one at a time i.e comment out article header then date works.

Comment: So you need to perform both search parameters at that time?

Comment: yes that's the case

Comment: In this query operator the same for all conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Azhar can you please check this query it's working fine in both cases.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempItems

CREATE TABLE #TempItems
(
    DateEffective DATE,
    ArticleHeader NVARCHAR(50)
)

insert into #TempItems values ('2019-12-28','Nieuws')
insert into #TempItems values ('2020-02-12','Test')
insert into #TempItems values ('2020-01-10','zolo')
insert into #TempItems values ('2020-02-23','valued')
insert into #TempItems values ('2020-02-24','Nieuws')

declare @DateEffective datetime,@operator nvarchar(10)
set @DateEffective ='2020-01-10'
set @operator='startswith'
declare @ArticleHeader nvarchar (50) ='Nieuws'

select * from #TempItems PA
Where 1=1
--------------------------------------------------------------------
And
(
(
(@operator='neq') And
CASE WHEN @DateEffective IS NULL 
THEN '1900-1-1' 
ELSE convert(date,PA.DateEffective) 
END !=
CASE WHEN @DateEffective IS NULL 
THEN '1900-1-1' 
ELSE Convert(Date, @DateEffective)
End
)
OR
(
(@operator='eq') And
CASE WHEN @DateEffective IS NULL 
THEN '1900-1-1' 
ELSE convert(date,PA.DateEffective) 
END =
CASE WHEN @DateEffective IS NULL 
THEN '1900-1-1' 
ELSE Convert(Date, @DateEffective)
End
)
OR
(
    1=1
)
)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
AND
(
(lower(@Operator) = 'eq' AND 
CASE WHEN @ArticleHeader IS NULL
            THEN '1'
            ELSE PA.ArticleHeader
      END =
      CASE WHEN @ArticleHeader IS NULL
                    THEN '1'
                    ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), @ArticleHeader)
      END
)
OR
(lower(@Operator) = 'startswith' AND 
CASE WHEN @ArticleHeader IS NULL
            THEN '1'
            ELSE PA.ArticleHeader
      END Like 
      CASE WHEN @ArticleHeader IS NULL
                    THEN '1'
                    ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), @ArticleHeader) + '%'
      END
)
OR
(lower(@Operator) = 'neq' AND 
CASE WHEN @ArticleHeader IS NULL
            THEN '1'
            ELSE PA.ArticleHeader
      END <> 
      CASE WHEN @ArticleHeader IS NULL
                    THEN '1'
                    ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), @ArticleHeader) 
      END
)
)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> Output

[image]

> Startwith
>   [image]

Comment: hey @jishan it works for neq  but as soon as i put 'startswith'  operator it dosen't return result , and if i change the Conjunction (AND)  with OR it works please have a look.

Comment: Sure ill check and get back to you.

Comment: @AzzFalconer can you please check in `start with` you don't have any `@DateEffective ` related condition you need to pass `1=1` for returning output :)