# In SQL Use "case when" for different columns based on condition in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write Stored Procedure where I could apply filters on different columns based on condition. Here I am using `Case When` in where clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE 
   Col = @ColValue
   And
   CASE @Parameter 
   WHEN 'Value1' THEN Column1 = @Col1Value
   WHEN 'Value2' THEN Column2 = @Col2Value...
```

Something similar to this query where I could apply filter on different columns based on condition or parameters passed to Stored Procedure.

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359272/sql-condition-based-searching-not-working-with-and-condition/60359486#60359486

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the exact logic to apply case when in where clause to match different columns with different parameters.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE
CASE @Parameter
WHEN value1 THEN Column1
WHEN value2 THEN Coumn2
END
=
CASE @Parameter
WHEN value1 THEN @ParameterValue1
WHEN value2 THEN @ParameterValue2
END
```

Here depending on parameter value we are choosing column and it's respective value in where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `case`.  Just use basic logic:

```
WHERE Col = @ColValue AND
      ( (@Parameter = 'Value1' AND Column1 = @Col1Value) OR
        (@Parameter = 'Value2' AND Column1 = @Col2Value) OR
        (@Parameter IS NULL)
      )
```

That said, you should be careful with stored procedures and performance.  You might want to recompile the logic -- or even use dynamic SQL -- to be sure that the most efficient query plan is generated for given parameters.  But that is another matter.

Comment: Yes this logic also give exact result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE
    (@Condition = 1
    AND ColumnName1 = 'xxxx')
OR
    (@Condition = 0
    AND ColumnName1 = 'xxxx'
    AND ColumnName2 = 'yyyy')
```

Comment: Correct, but can you update your query to match the exact logic in the original question?

Comment: Yes, This seem to be optimize query some where but can't we use exactly like switch case as in program to apply filter on different columns